# Fadein Background Image After Loaded in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am posting this because I have yet been able to find a good resource on fading in a background image only after it has been loaded. With jQuery, I fadeIn background images after they have loaded with this code:

```
    $('.img-col').each(function () {
     var $wrapper = $(this);
     var $img = $wrapper.find('.image');
     var tempImg = new Image();
     tempImg.src = $img.data('src');
     tempImg.onload = function () {
      $img.css('background-image', 'url(' + tempImg.src + ')');
      $wrapper.addClass('loaded');
     };
    })
```

The following is what I have so far in Angular 7. It seems to work but I know the code is not correct. The double reference to class in the html is necessary but clearly not right.

Component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 title = 'test-app';
 imageSrc: any;
 invisible: any;
 ngOnInit(){
  this.imageSrc = "https://www.producemarketguide.com/sites/default/files/valencia-oranges_variety-page.png";
 }
 onImageLoad(){
  this.invisible = "visible";
 }
}
```

Component.html:

```
<img [ngClass]="invisible" class="invisible" [src]="this.imageSrc" (load)="onImageLoad()" />
```

Component.css:

```
.invisible{opacity:0}
.visible{opacity:1; transition: opacity 1.6s ease;}
```

[StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fadein-working?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

What is the correct way to write this code, or perhaps a better method of getting a background image to fadein ONLY AFTER it has fully loaded in Angular 7?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve? just image should fade in when it appears?

Comment: I added a question at the bottom to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use angular animations here, I've tried that first time so don't judge me so much, check out **app.component.ts**, **app.component.html** and **app.component.css** in this example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fadein-working-thed9o?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I've changed it a little bit. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sure, i'm glad that it helped you!

Comment: You can learn about angular animations on angular.io, they have there really good explanation.

Comment: That solution unfortunately does not work if image is lazy loaded.